# How to comply DRY principle if two functions are almost the same?

Tags: c#, .net, dry

I have two functions which are almost the same. Is there a good way to remove duplicates?

I think about moving duplicated code in the separate function and pass a function as the argument.

```
private object GetValue(object key)
    {
        var index = GetHash(key);
        var node = _table[index];

        while (node != null)
        {
            if (Equals(node.Key, key)) return node.Value;

            node = node.Next;
        }

        throw new KeyNotFoundException("Such key doesn't exist");
    }

private void SetValue(object key, object value)
    {
        var index = GetHash(key);
        var node = _table[index];

        if(value == null) RemoveValue(key);

        while (node != null)
        {
            if (Equals(node.Key, key)) 
            {
               node.Value = value;
               return;
            }

            node = node.Next;
        }

        throw new KeyNotFoundException("Such key doesn't exist");           
    }
```

Comment: Depends on what you really want/need to do. In your SetValue method i see the following problems: (A) you throw the exception unconditionally. I guess you want to return from the method as soon as you have assigned node.Value, or do you intend to do something else/more in this method? (B) Is it guaranteed that there is always a node list/chain in _table at the index returned by GetHash?

Comment: @elgonzo (A) yeah, I have just added return statement. (B) It's not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, seems reasonable.

```
private Node GetNode(object key) 
{
  var index = GetHash(key);
  var node = _table[index];
  while (true)
  {
    if (node == null)
      throw ...
    if (Equals(node.Key, key))
      return node;
    node = node.Next;
  }
}
private object GetValue(object key) => GetNode(key).Value;
private void SetValue(object key, object value)
{
  if (value == null)
    RemoveValue(key);
  else 
    GetNode(key).Value = value;
}
```

Now, always ask yourself "how can I improve this further?"  Some thoughts:

- Why are these methods private? Are they implementation details of a nice public API, with a proper indexer?
- Object, in 2018?  Use generics!
- And so on.

Comment: It's just task.
1. I need to implement the previous set interface, not more or less.

2. Yeah object, just to understand how Hashtable works

Answer (score 2):

Split each of your methods in two parts:

- Finding the target node (private helper), and
- Doing something to the target node if it exists

Finding the target node should have this signature:

```
private Node FindNodeByKey(object key) {
    ...
}
```

This method would be in charge of throwing `KeyNotFoundException`, so both getter and setter could assume that when `FindNodeByKey` returns a value, it is not `null`. This assumption lets you reduce the getter to a single line:

```
private object GetValue(object key) {
    return FindNodeByKey(key).Value;
}

private void SetValue(object key, object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        RemoveValue(key);
    } else {
        FindNodeByKey(key).Value = value;
    }
}
```